# string arrays in x86 assembly: get a line at a time

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I am reading in a file of 3 books with title, author, and date.

What I want to do is process each line into a new array. I am having a problem only grabbing a line of data and adding it to a temp array.

I cant point to the beginning of the line and to the end of the line by looking for carriage return and incrementing `EDI`.

I will try to keep this as short as possible and only show you what I think you may need.

```
data?
array DWORD 2000 DUP(?)
new_array DWORD 2000 DUP(?)
```

i have a read file macro where i read in the file into hMem.

```
mov nums, InputFile("input.txt")
parse_file nums
```

Then I am trying to parse the file:

```
parse_file MACRO nums

mov EDI, nums
cld
repne scasb ; 

inc EDI     ;
```

I can calculate the length of the title but not sure how i could use that to grab the title. Maybe, i have been at my computer too many hours to see a solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`rep movsb` copies data from `[ds:esi]` to `[es:edi]`.